# Why can I import 'firebase/firestore' into my Firebase Cloud Function without installing the package?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am writing some Firebase Cloud Functions in TypeScript and I added `import { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';` to the top of my file because I needed `Timestamp` for one of my interfaces.

I do not have the `firebase` package installed, but to my surprise it worked just fine. I could use `Timestamp` in my TypeScript interface without error.

This is what my `package.json` looks like:

```JSON
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/secret-manager": "^4.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.18.0",
    "googleapis": "^103.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

As you can see the `firebase` package is not installed.

Why am I able to import it without having it installed?

Does it come 'pre-loaded' somehow?

EDIT:

As requested in the comments, I am adding the folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Could you also check if your `package-lock.json` doesn't have the `firebase` package. As far as I know, `firebase` is still not pre-loaded on initialization. You may have installed it somewhere.

Comment: My `package-lock.json` does not have the `firebase` package. But the functions folder that holds `package.json` and `package-lock.json` etc for the functions is housed within my app project. That app project does have the `firebase` package installed. Maybe is it looking further up the "chain" and using the `firebase` package from my app?

Comment: Could you please include your folder structure in your question for us to further help you.

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB A screenshot of the folder structure has been added. The functions in question and their associated `package.json` files are located in the `functions` folder. And above that, in the project root, I also have other `package.json` files for the app it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot of your application directory, you have multiple initialisation of `node_modules`. In your case, you have a `package.json` on the root folder that makes the `firebase` package installed on the ***top-level*** of your application. That just means it's inherited to the whole project and that you can use the `firebase` package on ***any*** directory/folders inside the root directory and its subdirectories. On the other hand, the `package.json` inside the `src` folder can only be used ***inside*** the `src` folder. More details on the illustration below.

e.g:

```
- function
  |_ node_modules
  |_ src
  |  |_ node_modules
  |  |_ package.json (package B)
  |_ package.json (package A)
```

`package.json` (package B):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
    "firestore-export-import": "^0.17.0"
  }
}
```

`package.json` (package A):

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.6.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0",
    "firestore-export-import": "^0.17.0"
  }
}
```

In the examples above, package A has the `firebase` but doesn't have the `express` library meanwhile, the package B has the `express` but doesn't have the `firebase` library. Inside the `src` folder, you can import all the libraries installed from the **package A** and **package B** but outside the src folder, specifically, the root of the function folder, you can only import **package A**.

Comment: is this solution only good for import in development? I tried the way you suggested but it throws an error in deployment, complaining about missing `express`. The reason is `node_modules` having is under the `src` folder. But after Typescript transpile to Javascript, the function look for module `express`, which is absent from `functon/node_modules`. Do you have any way to handle this situation?